# `RLMArray` does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'

Tags: swift, realm, swift4, codable

I want to Do:

- Using `JSONDecoder()`, I convert `json` to `Realm` object.
- And I save this object to `Realm` databases.

Problem:

- `RLMArray` don't apply `Codable` protocol.
- I could be conformed `Decodable` protocol, but `Codable` I couldn't.

Error Message:

- Type 'Person' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'

Code:

```
public class Hobby: Object, Codable {
    @objc dynamic var  title: String?
    @objc dynamic var  category: String?
}
public class Person: Object, Codable { // Error: Type 'Person' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'
    @objc dynamic var  name: String?
    @objc dynamic var  hobbies: RLMArray<Hobby>?

    required convenience public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.init()
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        hobbies = try container.decode(RLMArray<Hobby>?.self, forKey: .hobbies)
    }
}
func sample() {
    let person = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Person.self, from: "{\"name\" : \"aaa\",\"hobbies\" : [{\"title\" : \"fishing\",\"category\" : \"outdoor\"},{\"title\" : \"reading\",\"type\" : \"indoor\"}]}".data(using: .utf8)!)
    print(person)
    let realm = try! Realm()
    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(person!)
    }
}
```

Do you have some ideas?

Swift4
RealmSwift

Comment: I just wouldn't use the same class for the database schema definition and the API response.

Comment: Why are you using `RLMArray` at all in this code snippet? Your class derives from `Object`, indicating that you're using Realm Swift, so you should be using `List`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce In the end, I decided to divide into the database schema definition and the API response, because API response was complex. Thank you very much.

Comment: @bdash I was mistaken. `List` was correct. Thank you the useful advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Codable is the exact same as Decodable + Encodable. If you want to conform to Codable you will need to implement the encoding functions, which for your Person object would be:

```
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case hobbies
// or: case hobbies = "customHobbiesKey" if you want to encode to a different key
}

func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    do {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
        try container.encode(hobbies, forKey: .hobbies)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Add this to your Person class, and then implement the same thing for your Hobby class.

Because i'm not sure if you even want to encode: If all you need to do is create Realm-Objects from Json I would simply replace 'Codable' with the'Decodable'-Protocol.

EDIT: I noticed the issue is about the RLMArray. I'm not sure how codable works with RLMArray, but if it doesn't work you could try replacing the declaration with

`let hobbies = List<Hobby>()`

and then in init() replace the 'hobbies' line with:

```
let tempHobbyList: [Hobby] = try container.decode([Hobby].self, forKey: .hobbies)
self.hobbies.append(objectsIn: tempHobbyList)
```

That's how I got my lists with realmObjects to work with codable

Comment: Thank you for your useful advice. 
In the end, I decided to divide into the database schema definition and the API response, because API response was complex. 
However I'm very happy to be able to obtain this answer.
I use this way when I use simple API. Thank you very much.